# React Native Redux State Update Holds Navigation Call

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have two pages in my react native app:

1. Displays a list of data with `id`s and `title`s. By pressing on item, we should set an ID of current data type in redux and set `state.current` by finding an item inside a redux slice which has all `data`. Then, we navigate to next page.

example:

```
    setCurrentData: (state, action) => {
      state.current = dataAdapter
        .getSelectors()
        .selectById(state, action.payload.id)
    },
```

selectors:

```
export const getCurrentCommunity = state => state.allData.current
```

2. Second page gets the data by calling `useSelector(getCurrentCommunity)` and displays it.

Everything works well and i pass/fetch the data correctly from redux. The problem is that computations before navigation are really slow. Setting data in redux runs fast (`performance.now()` shows good results), but something after that state update is holding my navigation call.

Of course, i can just pass the data as a param, but it is not an option because later i would like to fetch it without passing anything to common components without routing.

What can i do to speed up the redux state update and make my navigation call faster?

btw, if i remove redux state setters, navigation works perfectly, 70-80ms delay (comparing to 2-3 seconds with redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself that `setCurrentData` action - duplicating your data within your store is a bad practice, and derived data like this should just be part of your selectors.

Instead just set the current page id (if that is even necessary)

```js
    setCurrentId: (state, action) => {
      state.currentId = action.payload.id
    },

const dataSelectors = dataAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.allData)
export const getCurrentCommunity = state => dataSelectors.selectById(state, state.allData.currentId)
```

Or even skip the action completely:

```js
const dataSelectors = dataAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.allData)
export const getCurrentCommunity = (state, id) => dataSelectors.selectById(state, id)
```

and call

```js
useSelector(state => getCurrentCommunity(state, idFromNavigationProp)
```

Comment: that is an interesting approach, i will try it in a bit and reply, thank you!